# Meu site carrega páginas diferentes em diferentes Sistemas Operacionais

Tags: laravel-4, linux, ubuntu, laravel-rotas, sistema-operacional

Estou passando por um problema muito estranho.

Ao utilizar Windows (Windows 7), minha pagina é carregada como esperado:

```
@extends + index.php
```

Já no Linux (Ubuntu 13.10) ele esta me redirecionando para a rota **/user/login** sem motivo algum:

```
@extends + login.php
```

Em ambos os sistemas, a pasta foi copiada do dropbox sem a vendor e instalado posteriormente via **composer install**

Achei que no filtro ou nas rotas pudesse haver algo conflitando, mas não faz sentido em um sistema carregar normalmente e no outro chamar por uma pagina inesperada.

**Rota:**

```
<?php

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Route model binding
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::model('user', 'User');
Route::model('comment', 'Comment');
Route::model('post', 'Post');
Route::model('role', 'Role');

Route::resource('upload', 'UploadController');


/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Admin Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'before' => 'auth'], function()
{
    Route::pattern('user', '[0-9]+');
    Route::pattern('role', '[0-9]+');

    # User Management
    Route::get('users/{user}/show', 'AdminUsersController@getShow');
    Route::get('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@getEdit');
    Route::post('users/{user}/edit', 'AdminUsersController@postEdit');
    Route::get('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@getDelete');
    Route::post('users/{user}/delete', 'AdminUsersController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('users', 'AdminUsersController');

    # User Role Management
    Route::get('roles/{role}/show', 'AdminRolesController@getShow');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@getEdit');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/edit', 'AdminRolesController@postEdit');
    Route::get('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@getDelete');
    Route::post('roles/{role}/delete', 'AdminRolesController@postDelete');
    Route::controller('roles', 'AdminRolesController');

    # Optional
    Route::get('faq', 'AdminUsersController@getFaq');
    Route::get('profile', 'AdminUsersController@getProfile');
    Route::get('mural', 'AdminUsersController@getMural');

    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::controller('/', 'AdminDashboardController');
});

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  User Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
Route::group(['prefix' => 'user', 'before' => 'auth'], function()
{

    // User reset routes
    Route::get('reset/{token}', 'UserController@getReset')
    ->where('token', '[0-9a-z]+');
    // User password reset
    Route::post('reset/{token}', 'UserController@postReset')
    ->where('token', '[0-9a-z]+');
    //:: User Account Routes ::
    Route::post('{user}/edit', 'UserController@postEdit')
    ->where('user', '[0-9]+');

    # Admin Dashboard
    Route::controller('/', 'UserDashboardController');
});

/** ------------------------------------------
 *  Frontend Routes
 *  ------------------------------------------
 */
//:: User Account Routes ::
Route::post('user/login', 'UserController@postLogin');

# User RESTful Routes (Login, Logout, Register, etc)
Route::controller('user', 'UserController');

# Index Page - Last route, no matches
Route::get('/', ['before' => 'detectLang','uses' => 'UserController@getIndex']);
Route::post('/', ['before' => 'detectLang','uses' => 'UserController@postIndex']);
```

**Filtro:**

```
<?php

App::before(function($request)
{
    //
});


App::after(function($request, $response)
{
    //
});

Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        Session::put('loginRedirect', Request::url());
        return Redirect::to('/');
    }
});

Route::filter('auth.basic', function()
{
    return Auth::basic();
});

Route::filter('guest', function()
{
    if (Auth::check()) return Redirect::to('/');
});

// Check for role on all admin routes
Entrust::routeNeedsRole( 'admin*', array('admin'), Redirect::to('/') );

// Check for permissions on admin actions
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/blogs*', 'full', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/comments*', 'full', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/users*', 'full', Redirect::to('/admin') );
Entrust::routeNeedsPermission( 'admin/roles*', 'full', Redirect::to('/admin') );

Route::filter('csrf', function()
{
    if (Request::ajax()){
        if (Session::getToken() != Request::header('X-CSRF-Token')){
            throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
        }
    }else if (Session::getToken() != Input::get('csrf_token') && Session::getToken() != Input::get('_token')){
        throw new Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;
    }
});

Route::filter('detectLang',  function($route, $request, $lang = 'auto')
{

    if($lang != "auto" && in_array($lang , Config::get('app.available_language')))
    {
        Config::set('app.locale', $lang);
    }else{
        $browser_lang = !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']) ? strtok(strip_tags($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']), ',') : '';
        $browser_lang = substr($browser_lang, 0,2);
        $userLang = (in_array($browser_lang, Config::get('app.available_language'))) ? $browser_lang : Config::get('app.locale');
        Config::set('app.locale', $userLang);
        App::setLocale($userLang);
    }
});
```

**Index:**

```
@extends('layouts.default')

@section('header')
@parent
@stop
```

**no Windows:**
[image: windows]

**no Ubuntu:**
[image: linux]

Comment: Tudo indica que você está "logado" no Windows, mas não está "logado" no Ubuntu - e, portanto, é redirecionado para a página de login.

Comment: @J.Bruni mas isso tem ligação direta com o Laravel ? no caso como faria para 'logar' no ubuntu ? se voce se refere a logar no site, ambos não estão autenticados, e a minha suposta pagina index.php não requer autenticação.

Comment: No Windows a sessão ficou salva no navegador, já no Ubuntu não.

Comment: @user5631 ja limpei todo cookie e sessão do navegador, aparentemente não tem nada salvo. Já testei em outro navegador tambem.

Comment: @user5631 sessão tem a ver com o navegador, não com o sistema operacional

Comment: Cara pelo que parece no ubuntu cai if guest do filter auth - tente retirar essa verificacao no filter auth e veja o que acontece

Comment: Checou maiúsculas e minúsculas nos paths todos? No Windows não muda nada, mas em outros "OSes" dá diferença.